# how to import data into spcial character column name using LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, load-data-infile, csv-import

under following sample im trying to import CSV data into MySQL table,

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file1.csv'
INTO TABLE loc_chg_log
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5) set failename=@col1,path=@col2,==blank=@col3,!=blank=@col4,++code=@col5;
```

MySQL table query is like this,

```
CREATE TABLE `log`.`loc_chg_log` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` VARCHAR(225) NULL,
  `path` VARCHAR(225) NULL,
  `==blank` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `!=blank` VARCHAR(125) NULL,
  `++code` VARCHAR(45) NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

none of these methods work's since the column name includes special character's, im getting error "unknown column'==blank' in field list"

```
1. '==blank'=@col5
2. ("`!=blank`=@col7")
3. [==blank=@col5]
```

Comment: Where is **++code** and **process_date** column in table ?

Comment: Can you try just putting either backticks or double quotes around the column name, e.g. `"==blank"=@col3`, or the same with backticks?  If neither of these work, you can always manually edit the source file and give proper column names.  Honestly, even if you could make this `LOAD DATA` statement work, you'd probably have to rename all the columns anyway.

Comment: First please correct the data which you put in question, table name mismatch in both create table and in load table syntex, and also correct the column name in table.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Haha!! thank you for notifying the differences, but this is the correct question.

Comment: If the question is correct then why there is difference between table names and in column names check the column names **=!blank** vs **!=blank**

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did try with double quotes and backticks as well, none of these work, and I needed the column name as I mentioned in the question. or what if I change the column name '++ code' into 'code[added]' still I have the same situation isn't it? thank you.

Comment: Honestly, the easiest thing to do here is to just use valid MySQL column names in your table which don't require escaping.  Why do you want to use names like `==blank` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well!!, I get a cloc csv output of a repository, in that case, I needed to know how many codes were added and deleted, even in the output csv file is like  `++code` and `--code`.

Comment: Why can't you use normal column names and then maybe create a temp table with the funky column names, and write that temp table to CSV?  Not sure I see what the hold up is here.

Answer (score 0):

by `'==blank'=@col5` putting backticks in the column name, I was able to write on data in MySQL database. thank you